# Can an adverb modify a preposition?

Tags: grammaticality

Source: p 37, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005) by Huddleston and Pullum

> Nevertheless, subordinate subjunctives like [iii] are structurally
>   **very like** subordinate clauses with primary verb-forms...

Please help me dig deeper than the bolded's  meaning, which I ask NOT about.

I guess here: **very** is an adverb (see [Defn 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/very)), and **like** is a preposition (see [Defn 1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/like)). Am I right?

The bolded phrase sounds grammatically strange and wrong.
What about in general, for any adverb and preposition?

Comment: = "very similar to"

Comment: @snailboat Thanks. I understand the meaning, but not the grammar.

Comment: See also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83952/when-can-very-modify-a-prepositional-phrase. By the way, *very near someone/something* (another *very* + preposition structure mentioned in that question) sounds quite fine to me, e.g. *[Caldwell, of marines, who was standing very near me on the gangway, having observed, "Sir, she then fired at us,” caused me pause for a moment, ...](https://books.google.com/books?id=CutHAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA546)*

Comment: Although I've heard "very like" umpteen times, I've only heard it from academics and writers. The man on the street says "very much like..."

Comment: @DamkerngT. +1. Thanks. This resembles a duplicate then, but I didn't know about that ELU post!

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem with modifying prepositions, such as *like* or many others where a notion of "how much" makes sense.

> In the game, he went straight toward the enemy.

*Straight* modifies *toward*, expressing "how much toward" (in this case, directly or *straight* toward).

Prepositions that express "targeting" (i.e. prepositions that identify an object of a phrase) obviously won't make sense with many modifiers, such as in most cases of *for*, *to*, *from*, etc.

> I did this for him.
>
> I did this very for him (Doesn't make sense.  It's either for him or *not* for him.)